# How gets an android app registered in the OS

Tags: android, android-service, nfc, apdu, hce

I'm searching the Android source code because I want to understand when the AndroidManifest.xml of an app gets parsed.

I.e. if an app registeres an NFC service

```
<service
        android:name=".demo.service.ApduService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>
```

with following apduservice.xml

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/servicedesc"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="false" >

<aid-group
    android:category="other"
    android:description="@string/aiddescription" >
    <aid-filter android:name="23498234098234098" />
</aid-group>
```

When and where does the Android OS read the aid-filter and registeres the ID?

(I know where it will be stored, and how, but I can't find the event where the actual ID gets extracted and forwarded to the NFC stack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When is the list of host and off-host CE services updated?**

The information about host and off-host APDU service (HCE and SE-based CE) is collected and updated whenever application packages are added, changed, updated, removed, etc. This is handled by a broadcast receiver in [com.android.nfc.cardemulation.RegisteredServicesCache](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/src/com/android/nfc/cardemulation/RegisteredServicesCache.java#90). The broadcast receiver is sensitive for the following events:

- `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`
- `ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED`
- `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`
- `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`
- `ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH`
- `ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED`
- `ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE`
- `ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE`

In addition, the AIDs are updated every time the NFC service is enabled.

**How and where is the list of services generated?**

During an update, the system is [queried](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/src/com/android/nfc/cardemulation/RegisteredServicesCache.java#169) for a list of services that filter for the intent actions `android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE` and `android.nfc.cardemulation.action.OFF_HOST_APDU_SERVICE`. For each service it is checked if the app holds the permission to use NFC and if the service requires the `BIND_NFC_SERVICE` permission. If that's the case, the services are considered for card emulation.

**How and where is the AID list extracted?**

The host and off-host APDU services are then stored in a list of [andoid.nfc.cardemulation.ApduServiceInfo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/cardemulation/ApduServiceInfo.java) objects. The [constructor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/cardemulation/ApduServiceInfo.java#107) of that class [processes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/cardemulation/ApduServiceInfo.java#112) the meta data specified in the `<service>` tag and [extracts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/cardemulation/ApduServiceInfo.java#174) the list of AIDs.

**How and where is the card emulation system updated with the new list?**

After the list has been compiled, it is passed to the [com.android.nfc.cardemulation.RegisteredAidCache](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/src/com/android/nfc/cardemulation/RegisteredAidCache.java#540). There, the list of services and AIDs is used to compile the routing tables for on-host and off-host AID routing.